# Excel multiple if function

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing the following issue, at the moment.

I would like to know if a value matches with a field. This field contains the following information:

9/4/2015 12:00:00 PM

Month/Day/Year hh:mm:ss

Now I want to compare my values with the field mentioned above.

```
  My values are: Day and Month.
  My idea is to create one term and just change the values in the term    
  every month (for the report).
```

e.g.

```
  IF Month = 10 and Day = 27 write Yes in a field. If not write No.
```

The problem is that a day or a month can have either two or one number:

```
9/4/2015 12:00:00 PM
10/25/2015 12:00:00 PM
1/12/2015 12:00:00 PM
12/1/2015 12:00:00 PM
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the day() month() functions?

Comment: or `=TEXT(A1,"mmdd")="1027"`

Answer (score 0):

The following forumula would do it without using VBA, comparing the value in A1 to a specific day and month using `IF` and `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A1)=10);--(DAY(A1)=27));"Yes";"No")
```